# Sequelize find soft deleted rows

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to get some rows from database that are soft deleted AND some that are not, but it's not working for me.

```
Model.findAll({
    'where': {
        cond: 'xxx'
    },
    include: [Model2],
    paranoid: false
}).then(function (rows) {
    // do something
}).catch(function (err) {
    // do something
});
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The query you have should include instances of `Model` that have been soft-deleted, but won't include instances of `Model2` that are soft-deleted.

To get the soft-deleted `Model2` instances, you'll also need the `paranoid: false` option within the `include`:

```
Model.findAll({
    'where': {
        cond: 'xxx'
    },
    include: [{
        model: Model2,
        paranoid: false
    }], 
    paranoid: false
}).then(function (rows) {
    // do something
}).catch(function (err) {
    // do something
});
```

This doesn't seem to be in the documentation, but I tried it and it worked.