# How to set paranoid: false for all queries in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

Is there any way to set `paranoid: false` for all queries from single place.

I want to do something like this.

```
this._sequelize = new Sequelize({
  dialect  : "mysql",
  host     : ENV_MYSQL_HOSTNAME,
  database : ENV_MYSQL_DB,
  username : ENV_MYSQL_USER,
  password : ENV_MYSQL_PASSWORD,
  query: {
    paranoid: false
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can configure a table to be paranoid or not at the model definition. You don't need to do it in any query, it means that any query under the model will be paranoid or not.

for example:

```
import { Model } from 'sequelize';


export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
   class myModel extends Model { 
       static applyAssociation = (models) => {
           // Apply accosiation
       };
   };

    myModel.init({
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            primaryKey: true,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        },
        // Any other columns
    },
        {
            sequelize,
            paranoid: true, // Or false - to your decision
            modelName: 'my_model',
            // Any other configurations
        }
    );

    return myModel;
};
```

Edit:
If you use `sequelize-typescript` add it in the `table` annotation:

```
@Table({
    timestamps: true,
    tableName: 'myModel',
    schema: dbConfiguration.dbSchema,
    paranoid: true,
    underscored: true,
})
```

Comment: I want models to be soft deleted, but i want them in query results as well

Comment: Do you mean to get the soft deleted rows upon a query?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do it from a single place (according to sequelize docs). You have to specify it in any query you do. A solution for this is to create an interface `IFindOptions` which will set paranoid to false and on any query extend it to the specific query.

Comment: Please check the following question to get soft-deleted records using sequelize - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659318/sequelize-find-soft-deleted-rows

Answer (score 0):

We can do it using sequelize model hooks (https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/hooks/)

#### `beforeFind` Hook

For example, if I need to run all find queries of a sample-model with `paranoid: false` (to get soft deleted rows along with non-deleted rows), I can add the `beforeFind` hook to my sample-model

```
const SampleModel = sequelize.define(
    'sample',
    {
        firstName: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
        }
    },
    {
        paranoid: true,
        hooks: {
            beforeFind: (options) => {
                options.paranoid = false;
            },
        },
    }
);
```

#### Global/Universal Hooks

We can configure same hooks for all models please refer [here](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/hooks/#global--universal-hooks)

`Sequelize: v6.21.4`